# How can I use layout data tags into blog's posts?

Tags: blogger

I am trying to use some layout data tags into a blog's post html code but with no luck!!!
There is any way to do that?

Here is an example...

```
<div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on">
    <div>This is a test text for <data:blog.title/> blog.</div>
    <br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Blogger tags in posts and pages.